# Readline on each iteration in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript and I do not know how to wait on each iteration to take input and print or process. I am working in node application.

```
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
  const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  readline.question('what should be tha name?', inputName => {
    console.log(`Hi ${inputName}`)
    readline.close();
  });
}
```

If I am putting `ray` as input for above it prints `Hi ray` for 3 times. I need it to take input for each time.

**UPDATE:**

I have made following changes but still it is working as per my need, when I press any letter it took it for all 3 iteration. i want 3 different input which will be taken synchronously.

```
const readline = require('readline');

askQuestion =  (query) => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(query, ans => {
        rl.close();
        resolve(ans);
    }))
}

const arr = [1,2,3]
arr.forEach(async element => {
    const ans = await askQuestion("Are you sure you want to deploy to PRODUCTION? ");
    console.log({ans})
});
```

Comment: I have updated question, it does not solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync):

```
const readline = require('readline-sync');

const arr = [1,2,3]
arr.forEach(() => {
    const ans = readline.question("Are you sure you want to deploy to PRODUCTION? ");
    console.log({ans})
});
```

Comment: awesome, this is what I was looking for!